# BackboneJS and Routing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have recently started getting into BackboneJS, for the most part I'm really liking it. I have a question though about routing.

Lets say I have 4 pages on my website.

home/

about/

info/

contact/

I want to use specific backbone models for each page - but not execute all the code on every page. For instance I have a slideshow on the homepage but I don't have one on the contact page. So there's no need to execute the slideshow code on that page. Is there a unique way to do it in backbone depending on the URI?

I know the routing covers data fragments but does it also cover the actual URI?

Apologies if this question sounds confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is it won't execute code of all pages at once..but yea it may load the code of all pages...If you want to avoid loading slideshow plugin code, i suggest you to load the plugin code dynamically only for that view...